# How can I call a function before it is defined in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `seeds.rb` file, I would like to have the following structure:

```
# Start of variables initialization
groups = ...
# End of variables initialization
check_data
save_data_in_database

# Functions go here
def check_data
  ...
end

def save_data_in_database
  ...
end
```

However, I got an error, because I call `check_data` before it is defined. Well, I can put the definition at the top of the file, but then the file will be less readable in my opinion. Is there another workaround?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Ruby, function definitions are statements that are executed exactly like other statement such as assignment, etc.  That means that until the interpreter has hit your "def check_data" statement, check_data doesn't exist.  So the functions have to be defined before they're used.

One way is to put the functions in a separate file "data_functions.rb" and require it at the top:

```
require 'data_functions'
```

If you really want them in the same file, you can take all your main logic and wrap it in its own function, then call it at the end:

```
def main
  groups =  ...
  check_data
  save_data_in_database
end

def check_data
  ...
end

def save_data_in_database
  ...
end

main # run main code
```

But note that Ruby is object oriented and at some point you'll probably end up wrapping your logic into objects rather than just writing lonely functions.

Answer (score 13):

Andrew Grimm mentions END; there's also BEGIN

```
foo "hello"


BEGIN {
def foo (n)
  puts n
end}
```

You can't use this to initialize variables because the {} defines a local variable scope.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `END` (upper case, not lower case)

```
END {
  # begin of variables initialization
  groups = ...
  # end of variables initialization
  check_data
  save_data_in_database
}
```

but that'd be a bit of a hack.

Basically, `END` code is run after all other code is run.

**Edit:** There's also `Kernel#at_exit`, ([rdoc link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001431))

Answer (score 3):

You could put the functions on another file and make a request on the top of the script.

Comment: Perhaps Kleber meant to say "make a *require* at the top of the script".

Comment: @Kleber S. if you edit your answer to fix that, it won't be misleading to people who don't read the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your initial calls in a function and call that function at the end:

```
# begin of variables initialization
groups = ...
# end of variables initialization

def to_be_run_later
  check_data
  save_data_in_database
end

# functions go here
def check_data
  ...
end

def save_data_in_database
  ...
end

to_be_run_later
```