# errors in deaf Grandma - Pine - No Method

Tags: ruby, function, ruby-1.9

Was completing the pine exercise for Def Grandma and thought would try and take it a little further and abstract it to remove as much duplication as possible.

Hope my logic with this isn't too bizzare just tried to separate things into functions. But now if I type

```
Bye
```

The program exits immediately without proceeding to the exitPlan function.
Any advice welcome.

```
puts 'Say something nice to Grandma.'
puts 'You may need to shout > '
speak = gets.strip
counter = 0
speaks(speak)

def speaks(speak)
    if speak != 'Bye'
        talk()
    else
        exitPlan()
    end
end

def talk()
    if speak == speak.downcase
        puts 'Huh Speak up Sonny'
        counter -= 1 
    else
        year = rand(1930..1951)
        puts 'No not Since ' + year.to_s
        counter -= 1
    end
        if counter < 0 
            counter = 0 # don't want counter going below zero.
            end
        puts 'Say something nice to Grandma'
        speaks()
end

def exitPlan()
    counter += 1
    unless counter == 3
        puts 'Say something nice to Grandma'
        speaks()
    else
        puts 'good night Sonny'
    end
end
```

Error

```
renshaw@renshaw-TravelMate-5740G:~/Ruby$ ruby -W dGrand.rb 
Say something nice to Grandma.
You may need to shout > 
Bye
dGrand.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `speaks' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
renshaw@renshaw-TravelMate-5740G:~/Ruby$
```

Comment: Are there any thrown exceptions? Because your methods doesn't know about the variables `counter` and `speak`, they are outside your methods scopes. Pass them around from method to method, or check out using a class or Global Variables http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the lines

```
puts 'Say something nice to Grandma.'
puts 'You may need to shout > '
speak = gets.strip
counter = 0
speaks(speak)
```

to after your method definition so that the `speaks` method has been defined when you reach the `speaks(speak)` line.

Then next problem you will probably encounter is

```
in `exitPlan': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

This is because `counter` is a local variable so is not shared between your toplevel code and the different methods. You will need to either use a global variable i.e. `$counter` for this or, better, put the various methods inside a class and then use an instance variable.

---

I suspect there are still some other issues in your code such as you only seem to be calling `gets.strip` to get the input once. However, in terms of wrapping the code inside a class it's not the counter that you want to wrap as you would still need to pass that around between the various methods. It's the whole speak/talk interaction so something along the lines of

```
class Grandma
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def speaks(speak)
    ..
  end

  def talk()
    ..
  end

  def exitPlan()
    ..
  end
end

grandma = Grandma.new
grandma.speaks(speak)
```

and substitute the places where you're currently using the local `counter` variable with references to `@counter`

Comment: From @Terw link I have found classes http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/classes.html  . Does that essentially mean that if I created a class counter with a def plus & def minus all the definition would need to be is say for plus counter += 1. Then start a new instance with say MyCounter = counter.new then I could us MyCounter.plus throughout the functions?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling method `speaks` before it's defined. See [Ruby: How to call function before it is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744237/ruby-how-to-call-function-before-it-is-defined)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the other posts explaining the use of methods and globals. [Here you have a gist](https://gist.github.com/1716721) that works with Ruby 1.9.3 because of how you used `rand`