# Classes Error in Ruby - NoMethod

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-1.9

Following on from the Grandma question here i wanted to take their advice and inplement the counter as a class. [Deaf Grandma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095047/errors-in-deaf-grandma-pine-no-method)

This is where I am at

```
puts 'Say something nice to Grandma.'
puts 'You may need to shout > '

class Counter
  counter = 0
  def Plus
    counter += 1
  end
  def Minus
    counter -= 1
  end
  def Reset
    counter = 0
  end
end

MyCounter = Counter.new

def speaks()
    $speak = gets.strip
    if $speak != 'Bye'
        talk()
    else
        exitPlan()
    end
end

def talk()
    if $speak == $speak.downcase
        puts 'Huh Speak up Sonny'
    else
        year = rand(1930..1951)
        puts 'No not Since ' + year.to_s
    end
        MyCounter.Minus
        if counter < 0
            Counter.reset
        end
        puts 'Say something nice to Grandma'
        speaks()
end

def exitPlan()
    MyCounter.Plus
    unless counter == 3
        puts 'Say something nice to Grandma'
        speaks()
    else
        puts 'good night Sonny'
    end
end
speaks()
```

This is the NoMethod Error

```
C:\Users\renshaw family\Documents\Ruby>ruby gran2.rb
Say something nice to Grandma.
You may need to shout >
Hi
No not Since 1939
gran2.rb:10:in `Minus': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from gran2.rb:35:in `talk'
        from gran2.rb:22:in `speaks'
        from gran2.rb:52:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
class Counter
  counter = 0
end
```

`counter` is a local variable and disappears *when you exit the class definition*, this means that it does not exist at any time later on, and thus `counter` is `nil` and you are trying to call `-` on it (`nil`) when doing `counter -= 1`, which results in `NoMethodError`. What you seem to be trying to do is initialize an [instance variable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Instance_Variables) during instantiation:

```
class Counter
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def plus
    @counter += 1
  end

  def minus
    @counter -= 1
  end

  def reset
    @counter = 0
  end
end
```

The `initialize` method is the name for the constructor in Ruby, and is called when you call `Counter.new`. Also note that I have changed the method names to begin with a lowercase letter, as is convention: classnames are capitalized, methods and variables are lowercase.

I would also **highly** discourage using global variables (e.g. `$speak`).