# Why does a start function need to be declared at the end [RUBY]?

Tags: ruby

beginner question here,
Here is a piece of a little program I am building up. Not putting everything there but just the very end.

I don't quite understand why I need to declare my "start" function **at the end** and then **call it again right after**. What's the logic behind?

My first guess is that the entire code needs to be interpreted first before allowing my "start" function to trigger events.

Nevertheless, I can't figure out why I need to call it right after.

Hope I am being clear enough.

Thanks for your help!

```
def start
  puts "1. I want to be Solid Snake"
  puts "2. I want to be Aragorn"
  print "> "

  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if choice == "1"
    snake
  elsif choice == "2"
    aragorn
  else
    puts "Oops, you can only choose between 1 and 2, try again."
  end
end

start
```

Comment: Not an expert in Ruby, but in general, with`def start` you create a function, that will now exist in your application, however it won't run by itself, because this is just telling your app "this is function `start`, do this (what's in the body - between `def` and `end`), when I call it", you must invoke it, to tell the software "you remember `start`? Right, let's do it!".

Comment: "why I need to declare my "start" function at the end" - you don't have to. The only requirement is that you define it before you use it.

Comment: "and then call it again right after. What's the logic behind?" - the logic is that you essentially say "This is a piece of code that will start the program when I command. Ok, now let's start this".

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744352/1368554

To summarise, function definitions are statements that are executed in the order they appear in your script. If you move `start` in front for `def start` ruby will not know about the function and results in unresolved symbol.